# why when i edit bones and open mirror funtion,the other side move weird

Tags: bones, rigify

[here is the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSfUw.jpg)

I guess it is relative to bones'axis .i don't know.
and when i rotate both the character and the bones,thecharater's left arm distort.

[image: here is the image]

[here is the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2oe3.jpg)

Comment: The mirror is mirroring on the X axis, so your model is supposed to face to the Y axis. But your model is facing to the X axis.

Comment: @FFeller must be a mind reader?  ;-)

Comment: sry i don't know how to upload a video .i use rigyfy .when i change the character facing to y axcis .it' still not working

Comment: You have to do it in edit mode, or apply the rotation if you do it in object mode (ctrl+a).